# Can we migrate Visual Studio license from one dev server to an other

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

What will be the best way to migrate a visual studio license from one server to an other.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://my.visualstudio.com/ , get a product key, activate VS with the key on the new server.